# How to do next step in excel

Tags: excel

I want to solve an issue in excel.

I have this situation:
[image]

I have: IF(AND(POS1="N";POS2=2;VAL1-VAL2;0)

When itfinds S, itmust always subtract the two consecutive Ns. How can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain precisely what output you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, I want: x=10-20, y=30-20, z=50-30 (and not z=50-40 because I want always N-N)

Comment: You want to loop trough VAL values from last to first, excluding S values from POS and then do substractions. If you have Excel 365, you may benefit from FILTER function and then do your calcultions backwards. Otherwise, you'll need VBA for this

Comment: could you explain me how to do? I mean, the right formula, thakns

Comment: Check FILTER function. After filtering, just use an extra columns to do your calcs https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty sure if I understand your requirements and your example. But from my understanding you just want to do the following.

Just add another Column:
IF(POS1="A";VAL1-VAL2)

Comment: I want the subtraction only between the POS = "N".

Comment: In this case: VAL2-VAL1, VAL3-VAL2, VAL5-VAL3. did u understand?